# java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation using ormlite

Tags: java, android, proguard, ormlite, android-multidex

[image]
I am getting this error when using

```
 @DatabaseField (columnName = "scriptBlob", dataType = DataType.BYTE_ARRAY)
    private byte[] scriptBlob;
```

if i delete

```
 @DatabaseField (columnName = "scriptBlob", dataType = DataType.BYTE_ARRAY)
```

I will have no errors

I start getting the error after using multidex Application

Comment: Can you provide the full exception?  I can't read those images.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation ... also in debug I see cannot load Field class ... I think it is related to mutidex loading I have other classes which has  @DatabaseField (columnName = "scriptBlob", dataType = DataType.BYTE_ARRAY) and they don't cause problem

Comment: see this https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78144